# Ubuntu 13.04 login screen problem

Tags: login

I had installed Ubuntu 13.04 about a week or two ago. It had been working completely fine, until today. I have it dual-booted with Windows XP. I logged into Windows, and then due to some reason there was a power outage. When I rebooted the PC, I forgot to press any button and it logged onto Ubuntu automatically.
It did not load up the regular login screen but defaulted to a non-graphical session. I was prompted to login which succeeded.

Where do I go from here? How can I make Ubuntu launch with the default login manager again?

I am thinking of loading into Live USB and resetting GRUB (Currently it is BURG) and then, logging into some other version (kernel version) of Ubuntu. the last one was something ending with .19 and current one is .27. But before that, I would like to hear all your views, over fixing this.

Comment: Have you tried manually starting `lightdm` by executing the command? Also, you could have a look at the lightdm log with `vi /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` and maybe investigate errors in the latest Xorg-log with `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep "(EE)"`. 

By the way, as you don't seem to be much experienced on Linux without a GUI: you may quit the editor `vi` by typing in `:q` and hitting [Enter].

Comment: Yea I am quite new to linux itself. I will try that ':q' for now.

Comment: It worked. Restarted a few times and it is working without any problem. I don't know why it ever occurred.

Comment: Well the problem came back. Although I can simply restart it manually I want something to quit it manually. The ":q" did not work anyhow.

Comment: ":q" is just to leave the editor. It has no other function. Please be more precise with your replies. "It worked" means that starting by typing `lightdm` works? Did you look at the logs and see something suspicious?

Comment: I tried the code `vi /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` but it simply showed me lots of "~" stacked on top of each other. And then I could not write anything else in the editor. And also, I noticed that the editor was showing something like "ttyl" in front of "Ubuntu 13.04" on top. I don't know what it meant.

Comment: It most probably also said "[Permission Denied]" at the bottom. Obviously you don't have read access to the file (because it is owned by root with a permission of 600). Although one shouldn't normally do that, start `vi` as superuser by using `sudo vi`. You then should see the log output. Also you still haven't answered, if starting `lightdm` manually solves the problem temporarily. Askubuntu is not for long comment threads. Therefore, I recommend you analysing the log file thoroughly and if needed opening a new, more specific question. "tty1" stands for your first terminal, which is correct.